# Various Spring MVC RequestMapping configuration questions

Tags: spring-mvc, mapping, request

I have several (albeit related) questions about Spring MVC RequestMapping configuration:

1. Say I have a type-level RequestMapping annotation as follows: `@RequestMapping("/root/")`. What is the difference between adding this method-level RequestMapping: `@RequestMapping(value="leaf")` and that one: `@RequestMapping(value="/leaf")`? Notice the leading slash in second method-level mapping.
2. What is the difference between having this type-level RequestMapping: `@RequestMapping("/root/")` and that one `@RequestMapping("/root/*")`? Notice the star in second mapping.
3. Say I already have a type-level RequestMapping annotation. How do I override the type-level mapping at the method-level so that the type-level mapping is ignored (for a given controller)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- It should be same mapping in both cases - `/root/leaf` for both method level mapping
- Both are same, in both cases the type level mapping will be combined with the method level mapping to generate the full request path, so type level of `/root/*` with the method mapping will become `/root/leaf` - more rules are here - http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/AntPathMatcher.html#combine(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)
- I doubt if you can, type level mapping is combined with method level mapping to create the full path.

Comment: Thanks very much for this detailed reply and for the link too!